# Why can't I use ".update()" with a Django object?

Tags: django

I've been trying to update a Django object with:

```
object_name.update(name="alfred")
```

The thing is that when I get the object name this way:

```
object_name = myobject.objects.get(id=object_id)
```

the method update won't work.

But when I get the object this way:

```
object_name = myobject.objects.filter(id=object_id)
```

it will work

Why does this happen? Is it because the last object is a queryset?
Is there anyway to use .update with a django object?

thank you!

Comment: you can apply update on a queryset itself

Comment: refer documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: the `filter` method return a list of queryset on the other hand the `get` method return only 1 object so you have to do somthing like this with `filter`:  `object_name = myobject.objects.filter(id=object_id)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already stated, you can't use `.update()` on a model instance itself - unless you created the function on the model yourself.

`.update()` is being used on `querysets` (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)).

If you want to save the changes for a model instance, use `save()`, example:

```py
obj = MyModel.objects.get(...)
obj.some_field = 'some-other-value'
obj.save()
```

Also see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects) on how to save changes to objects.

Example on how you could implement `MyModel.update()`:

```py
class MyModel(...):
    ...  # fields etc.

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
           setattr(self, k, v)
        self.save()
```